# Typo 3 11.5.30 Bootstrap package 14.0.6 / unable to resize logo

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I want to resize my logo file in bootstrap package, but it does not work

> page.logo.file = fileadmin/xxxx/Bilder/Logos/website_logo4.png

> page.logo.height = 200

can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the default values from $navbar-heights.
This results in a larger navbar → larger logo.

You can change it via TypoScript Constants like so:

```
plugin.bootstrap_package.settings.scss {
 navbar-heights = (sm: 100px, md: 100px, lg: 200px, xl: 200px, xxl: 200px )
}
```

sm, md ... being the different breakpoint which can be changed in $grid-breakpoints

The default values for $navbar-heights are:

```
$navbar-heights: (
    xs: 70px,
    sm: 70px,
    md: 70px,
    lg: 100px,
    xl: 110px,
    xxl: 110px
) !default;
```

**Edit:**

max-height: calc(var(--mainnavigation-nav-height) * .65); is set directly in bootstrap_package /Scss/components/navbar/_brand.scss.
So it can't be changed via constant or SCSS var.

https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/1462f2fa848163ac54aab550582dd78c12e44e64/Resources/Public/Scss/components/navbar/_brand.scss#L22

Answer (score 0):

setting say:

```
    page.10.settings {
        logo {
            height = {$page.logo.height}
            width = {$page.logo.width}
            linktitle = {$page.logo.linktitle}
        }
    }
```

so try page.10.settings.logo.height = 200 ?

https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript

But in constants.ts it is indeed correct so maybe the order of loading the config is not right?

Comment: i have tried this, but it seems to be a conflict with:
.navbar-mainnavigation .navbar-brand-image img {
    max-height: calc(var(--mainnavigation-nav-height) * .65);
}

Comment: is there an option in Typo3 to change this value (0.65)?